# How to check if a specific record exists in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check if a record exist with id 10 in `users` table.

I was trying to use `exist` keyword in SQL, but I can't figure out the correct syntax for using `exist` to check whether a record exist.

I want something like below

```
If ( exist (select id * from table where Id = id ) ) 
{

}
```

Comment: `exist` should be `exists`. And SQL Server uses `BEGIN ... END` not braces.

Comment: @Dooby Inc - When the question itself is about invalid syntax please don't correct the syntax in the question. That is what the answers are for.

Comment: After 20k viewings one can probably assume that the question is not too unlikely to help any future visitors. It should be reopened. It may aquire more and better answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's so easy to use `Exist` keyword, 
I have written correct syntax below , check it out

```
if exists (select * from  [dbo].[table] where id= [the id you want to check] ) 
select 'True'  
else 
select 'False' 
return
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[dbo].[table]` instead of `[dbo.table]`?

Comment: You are right it should be dbo.table

Comment: If you need more than one statement within the condition, you'll need to use *BEGIN* and *END* keywords